# Image upload pulgin josegonzalez / cakephp-upload

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using this  "josegonzalez / cakephp-upload" plugin in cakephp to upload image. when i upload image it save in db and location as it is. Now i want to change image name also and that image name save in db and location. How can i do this through this plugin. If any one know please help me...

This is my code

```
public $actsAs = array(
    'Containable',
    'Upload.Upload' => array( 
        'img' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'dir' => 'img_dir'
                ),
                'thumbnailSizes' => array(
                    'big'   => '639x423',
                    'small' => '130x130',
                    'thumb' => '90x82'
                ),
                'thumbnailMethod' => 'php',
                'path'            => '{ROOT}webroot{DS}img{DS}brand{DS}{field}{DS}',
                'deleteOnUpdate'  => true
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You placed additional array wrap

```
public $actsAs = array(
    'Containable',
    'Upload.Upload' => array(
        'path' => '{ROOT}webroot{DS}img{DS}brand{DS}{field}{DS}',        
        'fields' => array(
            'dir' => 'img_dir'
        ),
        'thumbnailSizes' => array(
            'big'   => '639x423',
            'small' => '130x130',
            'thumb' => '90x82'
        ),
        'thumbnailMethod' => 'php',
        'deleteOnUpdate'  => true
        ),
        'thumbnailName' => '{filename}_{size}_{geometry}'
    )
);
```

Comment: i WANT TO CHANGE IMAGE NAME

Comment: @user3425009 You can change thumbnail name basing on my last edit

Comment: I will try first.. then i mark it right :) tomorrow